# Spring Boot - Error Controller to handle either JSON or HTML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application.

I have a custom error controller, that is mapped to using `ErrorPage` mappings.  The mappings are largely based on HTTP Status codes, and normally just render a HTML view appropriately.

For example, my mapping:

```
@Configuration
class ErrorConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

  @Override public void customize( ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container ) {
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error/404.html" ) )
  }
```

And my error controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping( value = "/error/404.html" )
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String pageNotFound( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        "errors/404"
    }
```

This works fine - If I just enter a random non-existent URL then it renders the 404 page.

Now, I want a section of my site, lets say `/api/..` that is dedicated to my JSON api to serve the errors as JSON, so if I enter a random non-existent URL under /api/.. then it returns 404 JSON response.

Is there any standard/best way to do this?  One idea I tried out was to have a `@ControllerAdvice` that specifically caught a class of custom API exceptions I had defined and returned JSON, and in my standard ErrorController checking the URL and throwing an apprpriate API exception if under that API URL space (but that didn't work, as the ExceptionHandler method could not be invoked because it was a different return type from the original controller method).

Is this something that has been solved?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last statement? It's not clear what you mean by _could not be invoked because it was a different return type_.

Comment: thanks @zeroflagL - I should have added more details - I am not at the code right now, but will add some more details when I am back.. this is more observed behaviour that I saw whilst testing, but wasnt exhaustive.. Another possibility is that because throwing code is in the ErrorController (so already in springs error handling process) the ControllerAdvice doesnt work the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my own fault.  I was trying to work out why my `@ExceptionHandler` was not able to catch my exception and return JSON - As I suggested at the end of my question, I thought I was having problems because of conflicting return types - this was incorrect.

The error I was getting trying to have my exception handler return JSON was along the lines of:

```
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
  "message": "Could not find acceptable representation"
```

I did some more digging/experimenting to try to narrow down the problem (thinking that the issue was because I was in the Spring error handling flow and in an `ErrorController` that was causing the problem), however the problem was just because of the content negotiation stuff Spring does.

Because my errorPage mapping in the `web.xml` was mapping to `/error/404.html`, Spring was using the suffix to resolve the appropriate view - so it then failed when I tried to return json.

I have been able to resolve the issue by changing my web.xml to `/error/404` or by turning off the content negotiation suffix option.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I want a section of my site, lets say /api/.. that is dedicated
>   to my JSON api to serve the errors as JSON, so if I enter a random
>   non-existent URL under /api/.. then it returns 404 JSON response.
>
> Is there any standard/best way to do this? One idea I tried out was to
>   have a @ControllerAdvice that specifically caught a class of custom
>   API exceptions I had defined and returned JSON, and in my standard
>   ErrorController checking the URL and throwing an apprpriate API
>   exception if under that API URL space (but that didn't work, as the
>   ExceptionHandler method could not be invoked because it was a
>   different return type from the original controller method).

I think you need to rethink what you are trying to do here. According to HTTP response codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

> The 404 or Not Found error message is an HTTP standard response code
>   indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given
>   server, but the server could not find what was requested.

So when typing a random URL you may not want to throw 404 all the time. If you are trying to handle a bad request you can do something like this

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {   

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> noRequestHandlerFoundExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException e) {
        log.debug("noRequestHandlerFound: stacktrace={}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));

        String errorCode = "400 - Bad Request";
        String errorMsg = "Requested URL doesn't exist";

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse(errorCode, errorMsg), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Construct `ResponseEntity` that suites your need.

Comment: I am happy that I should be 404-ing non-existent URLs (agree that if it was an invalid/syntactically illegal URL I would 400 them).  The default behaviour for Spring MVC is to 404 any request that doesn't match a mapped pattern (assuming it matches the dispatcherservlet context).  For example, if you try to enter a random URL here: http://stackoverflow.com/aaaa/bbbbb it 404s you.