# Using Spring Boot, how to separately handle exception between normal request and ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am implementing Java web application using Spring MVC and Spring Boot.

I would like to create a custom error page (For 404, 500 errors), I try to use the solution from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393578/2148445
and it works fine. However, it intercepts all the 404/500 errors even my ajax request. My web application is based on ajax request, so when I call API, it returns custom error page instead of json response.

I would like to:
     when normal request >> go to custom error page.
     when ajax request >> return error response as json object.

I try to find the other ways but I cannot get the good solution so far.
I tried to use `@ExceptionHandler`, but my colleague said that it will override Spring boot's.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you paste your ajax listener class?

Comment: I think it's a bit tricky. The best shot you can take would be to create a controller to handle the error, inject the `HttpServletRequest` to it and based on the requested path either return JSON or do redirect to error view.

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703903/spring-boot-error-controller-to-handle-either-json-or-html

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to send an "X-REQUESTED-WITH" header with value "XMLHttpRequest" when doing ajax calls from the browser.

On the backend side, you can check if this header with the given value is available to decide whether it was an ajax call or not.